# VIM shortcuts in coffeescript

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I am trying to build an app such that when you press "i" you go into insert mode. This is great and works however it currently inserts the character "i" into the text field. Below is what I have tried already and has FAILED

```
  $("body").keypress (e) ->
      if e.which == 105
        $("#_messages_content").focus()

  $("body").keypress (e) ->
      if e.which == 105
        $("#_messages_content").focus() && $("#_messages_content").val(" ")
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to prevent some actions: If the input already has the focus, you don't need to jump there again. Otherwise, you want to set the focus to the input, but prevent the default behavior, which is inserting an "i".

```
$('body').keypress (e) ->
  if e.which is 105
    $('#_messages_content').focus()
    e.preventDefault()   # Don't insert the "i"

$('#_messages_content').keypress (e) ->
  e.stopPropagation()​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​    # User is typing, don't propagate the event
```

http://jsfiddle.net/whXmj/

---

If you'd like to allow typing in all textfields, it may be easier to not stop the propagation of the keypress event everywhere, but to check where the event originates.

```
$('body').keypress (e) ->
  if e.which is 105 and e.target.nodeName.toUpperCase() is 'BODY'
    $('#_messages_content').focus()
    e.preventDefault()​​​​​​​​​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/whXmj/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to use the `keydown` event, since the `keypress` is triggered after the character was handled ([keydown, keypress, keyup](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html)).

so, maybe something like:

```
$("body").keydown (e) ->
    if e.which == 105
        e.preventDefault()
        $("#_messages_content").focus()
```

Comment: Keypress is fine, because it still fires before the character is inserted into the textfield. The difference is, that in keydown only information about which (actual) key was pressed is available, while in keypress you already know which character will be inserted. Meaning: When you do this using the keydown event, you need to check for `e.which == 73` (the I key), while in keypress you're able to check for a lowercase i (105).